# linux, Comma Separated Cells to Rows Preserve/Aggregate Column

Tags: linux, bash, unix

There was a similar question here but for excel/vba [Excel Macro - Comma Separated Cells to Rows Preserve/Aggregate Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473553/excel-macro-comma-separated-cells-to-rows-preserve-aggregate-column)
because i have a big file (>300mb) this is not an option, thus I am struggeling to get it to work in bash.

Based on this data

```
 1   Cat1                 a,b,c
 2   Cat2                 d
 3   Cat3                 e
 4   Cat4                 f,g
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
 1   Cat1                 a
 1   Cat1                 b
 1   Cat1                 c
 2   Cat2                 d
 3   Cat3                 e
 4   Cat4                 f
 4   Cat4                 g
```

Comment: Is this some kind of homework, where you have to do everything in bash itself? Or can you just use `awk` or something else more suited to the task?

Comment: No its not homework, i need to automate something that looks like this, so it would be nice to put it in a shell script. i will look into awk, thank you.

Comment: in line one and line 4 is there really a space between b, c and f, g? If so, is there a reason on line 1 it read a,b,[space]c? Last question are those line numbers actually in the file?

Comment: No there is no space, sorry.yes there is an extra column with numbers in the file, an identifier. The columns are tab seperated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat > data << EOF
1   Cat1                 a,b,c
2   Cat2                 d
3   Cat3                 e
4   Cat4                 f,g
EOF

set -f                               # turn off globbing
IFS=,                                # prepare for comma-separated data
while IFS=$'\t' read C1 C2 C3; do    # split columns at tabs
    for X in $C3; do                 # split C3 at commas (due to IFS)
        printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$C1" "$C2" "$X"
    done
done < data
```

Comment: The shell can do it, but for a large file, I expect awk or perl to be considerably faster.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for awk or perl.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
     { split($3, a, ",");
       for (i in a) {$3 = a[i]; print} }'
perl -F'\t' -alne 'foreach (split ",", $F[2]) {
                       $F[2] = $_; print join("\t", @F)
                   }'
```

Both programs are based on the same algorithm: split the third column at commas, and iterate over the components, printing the original line with each component in the third column in turn.