# Excel VBA Macro Taking Cells to Columns

Tags: database, excel, vba, spreadsheet

I have data stored within single cells:

```
 <- A (Category) ->   <- B (Items) -> <- C (Items) -> <- D (Items) -> <- E (Items) ->
  1   Cat1                 date1          a,b,c            a1,b1,c1        item1
  2   Cat2                 date2           d                  d1           item2
  3   Cat3                 date3           e,f                e1,f1        item3
  4   Cat4                 date4           g                  g1           item4
```

I want to transfer it to the following format:

```
 <- A (Category) ->   <- B (Items) -> <- C (Items) -> <- D (Items) -> <- E (Items) ->
  1   Cat1                 date1           a                  a1           item1
  1   Cat1                 date1           b                  b1           item1
  1   Cat1                 date1           c                  c1           item1
  2   Cat2                 date2           d                  d1           item2
  3   Cat3                 date3           e                  e1           item3
  3   Cat3                 date3           f                  f1           item3 
  4   Cat4                 date4           g                  g1           item4
```

(i.e. I want to break Columns C and D into new rows and copy the items in A,B, and E).

The code from [Excel Macro - Comma Separated Cells to Rows Preserve/Aggregate Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473553/excel-macro-comma-separated-cells-to-rows-preserve-aggregate-column) works perfect for two adjacent columns, but how do I copy a range of columns?

```vb
Sub ExpandData()
    Const FirstRow = 2
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("A" & CStr(Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Get the values from the worksheet
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Set SourceRange = Range("A" & CStr(FirstRow) & ":B" & CStr(LastRow))

    ' Get sourcerange values into an array
    Dim Vals() As Variant
    Vals = SourceRange.Value

    ' Loop through the rows in the array and split each comma-delimited list of items and put each on its own row
    Dim ArrIdx As Long
    Dim RowCount As Long
    For ArrIdx = LBound(Vals, 1) To UBound(Vals, 1)

        Dim CurrCat As String
        CurrCat = Vals(ArrIdx, 1)

        Dim CurrList As String
        CurrList = Replace(Vals(ArrIdx, 2), " ", "")

        Dim ListItems() As String
        ListItems = Split(CurrList, ",")

        Dim ListIdx As Integer
        For ListIdx = LBound(ListItems) To UBound(ListItems)

            Range("A" & CStr(FirstRow + RowCount)).Value = CurrCat
            Range("B" & CStr(FirstRow + RowCount)).Value = ListItems(ListIdx)
            RowCount = RowCount + 1

        Next ListIdx

    Next ArrIdx

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `,` in between the individual ranges

```vb
Set SourceRange = Range("A" & CStr(FirstRow) & ":B" & CStr(LastRow) & ",E" & _
                        CStr(FirstRow) & ":E" & CStr(LastRow))
```

will allow you to select the disjointed range.

Comment: Great answer, I have been looking for this for awhile. ~JOL