# Excel VBA Macro - Separate cell contents in a range by space into rows and capture original cell location

Tags: vba, excel

I have an inventory spreadsheet that has multiple entries per cell separated by spaces. They are using the current cell location as the reference number, so I need to maintain that information.

Example:
   Current

```
Cell A1 - PartA PartB PartC  
Cell A2 - PartD PartE
```

Desired

```
Cell A1 - PartA  Cell B1 - A 'OriginalColumn Cell C1 - 1 'OriginalRow  
Cell A2 - PartB  Cell B2 - A 'OriginalColumn Cell C2 - 1 'OriginalRow  
Cell A3 - PartC  Cell B3 - A 'OriginalColumn Cell C3 - 1 'OriginalRow  
Cell A4 - PartD  Cell B4 - A 'OriginalColumn Cell C4 - 2 'OriginalRow  
Cell A5 - PartE  Cell B5 - A 'OriginalColumn Cell C5 - 2 'OriginalRow
```

etc.

I've done my research and the closest VBA code does the split information, but it pastes it to the next row over, and for a range, that's no good for me. [SO: Comma Separated Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471435/excel-macro-comma-separated-cells-to-rows?rq=1)

I've tried altering the code to make it work for a range, but having troubles getting it to work and not sure what's wrong. I also am having a hard time figuring out how to capture the original cell location and output to the other rows. (If it can't be split from A1 to A & 1, I can live with that, but it's desired.)

Thanks in advance for any assistance in pointing the way!

Current code:

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub ToolFormat()

    Dim mainsheet As Sheet1
    Dim datalist As Sheet2
    Dim vLastRow As Long
    Dim vLastCol As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim x As Long



        With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            vLastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
            vLastCol = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column
        End With

    ' MsgBox ("Last row: " & vLastRow & " Last column: " & vLastCol)

        Dim toCol As String
        Dim toRow As String
        Dim inVal As Range
        Dim outVal As Range
        Dim commaPos As Integer

        Set inVal = Nothing

    For y = 1 To vLastCol

        For x = 1 To vLastRow

        ' Copy from mainsheet range to datalist column B.'

        toCol = "B"
        toRow = "1"

        ' Go until no more entries
        inVal = mainsheet.Cells(x, y).Value
        While inVal <> ""

            ' Go until all sub-entries used up.'
            While inVal <> ""
                Range(y + x).Select

                ' Extract each subentry.'
                commaPos = InStr(1, inVal, ",")
                While commaPos <> 0

                    ' and write to output column.'
                    outVal = Left(inVal, commaPos - 1)
                    datalist.Range(toCol + toRow).Select
                    datalist.Range(toCol + toRow).Value = outVal
                    toRow = Mid(Str(Val(toRow) + 1), 2)

                    ' Remove that sub-entry.'
                    inVal = Mid(inVal, commaPos + 1)
                    While Left(inVal, 1) = " "
                        inVal = Mid(inVal, 2)
                    Wend
                    commaPos = InStr(1, inVal, ",")
                Wend

                ' Get last sub-entry (or full entry if no commas).'
                Range(toCol + toRow).Select
                Range(toCol + toRow).Value = inVal
                toRow = Mid(Str(Val(toRow) + 1), 2)
                inVal = ""
            Wend

            ' Advance to next source row.'
            x = Mid(Str(Val(x) + 1), 2)
            mainsheet.Range(y + x).Select
            inVal = mainsheet.Range(y + x).Value
        Wend

        Next x ' until x.value = ""

    Next y



    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you desire (hopefully):

```
Sub SplitIt()
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10") 'change that as you need it (the data to be splited)
  Dim rngVal As Variant
  rngVal = rng.Value
  Dim xSpl As Variant, xSpl2 As Variant, xVal() As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, col As String
  j = rng.Row
  col = Split(Columns(rng.Column).Address(, 0), ":")(0)
  ReDim xVal(1 To 3, 0)
  For Each xSpl In rngVal
    If Len(xSpl) Then
      xSpl = Split(Trim(xSpl), " ")
      If UBound(xVal, 2) Then
        ReDim Preserve xVal(1 To 3, 1 To i + UBound(xSpl) + 1)
      Else
        ReDim xVal(1 To 3, 1 To UBound(xSpl) + 1)
      End If
      For Each xSpl2 In xSpl
        If Len(xSpl2) Then
          i = i + 1
          xVal(1, i) = xSpl2
          xVal(2, i) = col
          xVal(3, i) = j
        End If
      Next
    End If
    j = j + 1
  Next
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(i, 3) = Application.Transpose(xVal) 'Change the sheet and the "A1" to the upper left cell to output to
End Sub
```

it is designed to work only for one column with mutiple rows but do not use a range like "A:A" (just the range which contains values) or it may freeze excel for some time ;)

### How it works:

It checks each cell in the range if it has anything inside it (blank cells will be skipped, also cells only containing spaces).
Then each cell-value is split to an array (split by a space). This array will be attached to the existing output-array (again, empty parts will be skipped).

Thanks to the way `Redim Preserve` works, we get a transposed array which we need to transpose at the end for output. And that's all... (the part for column/row should be self explaining)

If you still have any questions, just ask ;)

Comment: @gary for future reference, how do I do the highlighting you did for the example cells? Is that the 'code' format?

Comment: Thanks @Dirk  I'll try the code tomorrow morning. If I may ask, how would you recommend I change the paste code so that it appends to the bottom of the rows? I don't want to separate one column, then overwrite that information when the next column gets processed.     
Something like:   
  
               ' TheLastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row  
  
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A"& TheLastRow).Resize(i, 3) = Application.Transpose(xVal) 'Change the sheet and the "A1" to the upper left cell to output to ' (Grrr! Can't get line breaks to work)